# Angular4 focus on component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, viewchild

I have a multi-picklist component that houses a list of checkbox components. The parent component has a CSS `:focus` and `:hover` class for the mouseover. All controllable elements are in the tab index (so you can awkwardly use the keyboard to tab through the checkboxes).

Now we want to allow arrow-key navigation in the multi-picklist. Basically I need to use `@ViewChild` to grab the element I need and set  `.focus()` to it. And that's exactly what I did in a different component, and that worked. However, here it does not work. The only difference is that in the component where it works my `*ngFor` loop iterates over a list of `div`s and in this case it does so over a list of components.

So what this boils down to is that I can't get the `:focus` pseudo class to stick to my component.The following code is not complete, just trying to get the first element focused. Sort of PoC.

MultiPicklist.component.html:

```
<div (keydown.ArrowDown)="arrowDownHit($event)">
  <div [hidden]="multiPicklistState === 'collapsed'" (keydown.Escape)="closeBox()" #multiPicklist>
    <app-checkbox              
      #checkboxItems
      class="multi-picklist-checkbox" 
      *ngFor="let item of picklistItemList; trackBy: trackByFunc; let i = index;"
      [fieldName]="item.value"
      [label]="item.label" 
      [chckbxId]="'multiPicklistChkbx'+title+i" 
      [tooltip]="item.tooltip" 
      [isChecked]="item.isChecked"
      (checkboxChanged)="inputChanged($event)">
    </app-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

MultiPicklist.component.scss:

```
.multi-picklist-checkbox:hover, .multi-picklist-checkbox:focus{
  background-color: $multi-picklist-item-hover-bg-color;
}
```

MultiPicklist.component.ts:

```
arrowDownHit(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  this.multiPicklist.nativeElement.firstElementChild.focus();
}
```

It's worth mentioning that the `:hover` pseudo class works, hovering the mouse over the component gives it the correct background color. But not `.focus()`. Furthermore, no error is thrown,.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround, not an actual answer or solution.

I was able to set the focus of an HTML element inside the component. It resulted in an ugly little line of code:

`this.multiPicklist.nativeElement.firstElementChild.lastElementChild.focus();`

Of course in an ideal universe I'd be able to just apply the focus to the entire component, or whatever `div` the browser ends up seeing.